# RecyclerView changing position randomly while scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have made a chat app where I have used a `RecyclerView`. Messages can be either text messages or audio messages. Everything is working fine except when I change the timer text on the `TextView` (for audio player layout I have made) , of how long has the song been played. I do this in a `Runnable`. But when I scroll the `RecyclerView`, the timer `TextView` changes text at random position.

Here is how I am changing the `TextView` text:

```
public void updateTimer(final int position) {
    View view = mRecyclerViewChat.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
    timer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timer);

     r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int currentDuration;
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                currentDuration = player.getCurrentPosition();
                timer.setText("" + milliSecondsToTimer((long) currentDuration));
                timer.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            } else {
                timer.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        }
    };

    timer.post(r);
}
```

Here `position` is the position value I am getting from the `onBindViewHolder`.

**EDIT**

Here is the `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (TextUtils.equals(mChats.get(position).senderUid,
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
        if (mChats.get(position).mediaUrlLocal == null) {
            configureMyChatViewHolder((MyChatViewHolder) holder, position);
        } else {
            configureMyChatMediaViewHolder((MyChatMediaViewHolder) holder, position);
        }
    } else {
        if (mChats.get(position).mediaUrlLocal == null) {
            configureOtherChatViewHolder((OtherChatViewHolder) holder, position);
        } else {
            configureOtherChatMediaViewHolder((OtherChatMediaViewHolder) holder, position);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the `playMedia` method which is called from `configureMyChatMediaViewHolder` method:

```
private void playMyMedia(final MyChatMediaViewHolder myChatViewHolder, final Chat chat, final int position) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    metaRetriever.setDataSource(chat.mediaUrlLocal);

    String duration =
            metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    long dur = Long.parseLong(duration);
    String seconds = String.valueOf((dur % 60000) / 1000);

    String minutes = String.valueOf(dur / 60000);
    String out = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    myChatViewHolder.timer.setText(out);

    if (chat.isPlay) {
        myChatViewHolder.play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myChatViewHolder.pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        myChatViewHolder.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myChatViewHolder.pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    myChatViewHolder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chat.isPlay = !chat.isPlay;
            if (previousChat != position && previousChat != -1) {
                previousChatObj = mChats.get(previousChat);
            }
            previousChat = position;
            myChatViewHolder.play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            myChatViewHolder.pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            callback.onPlayClickListener(chat, previousChatObj, position);
        }
    });

    myChatViewHolder.pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chat.isPlay = !chat.isPlay;
            myChatViewHolder.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myChatViewHolder.pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            callback.onPauseClickListener(chat, position);
        }
    });
}
```

I have only one media player instance in the fragment from which the adapter for chat is set.

Comment: Please post you `ViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder()` implementations. Using `final int position` as you do is wrong - you should never cache position of RecyclerView. Also it is not clear while look for timer TextView each time - it should be stored in ViedHolder, etc.

Comment: I've posted an answer, please let me know if it helps

Comment: One more idea: after recycling, your TextView may still have Runners attached to it. so **before** you call `myChatViewHolder.timer.setText(out);` call `myChatViewHolder.timer.removeCallbacks(myChatViewHolder.timer.getTag());`. In `updateTimer()` add last line `timer.setTag(r)`

Answer (score 0):

Recycler view is re-using the views that are not currently visible. So if your audio player starts updating one Text View , when you scroll that textview is the same reference but with different text ( song ), but your runnable instance is still active and doing its job to update the Text View with same reference.

1. You should create a custom Runnable class which
   will hold a position value and will be only responsible for the
   TextView it should update.
2. Other approach ( less efficient ) is to use ListView and not to re-use the cells to create new one for each item. **This will cause performance issues**

If you can send some code i would like to help you out.

*** EDITED ****

Here is some code part that can make things more clear

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.songDurationView.setTag(position);
        //TODO: implement some more logic here and start the MusicSongRunnable
    }



class MusicSongRunnable implements Runnable {

    int positionOfSong;
    TextView textView;

    public MusicSongRunnable(int positionOfSong, TextView textView) {
        this.positionOfSong = positionOfSong;
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (player.isPlaying() && positionOfSong == textView.getTag()) {
        //TODO: update the song;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the difference between what you said and what I have done? I am also holding a position value in the method, which should only be responsible for updating respective TextView

Comment: Not in the commet but a different class which implements Runnable and now exactly what TextView on which position to update. I have edited my answer hope it helps

Comment: the variable position in playMyMedia() is the index of the item that needs to be updated ?

Comment: Okey, try to attach the position to the textview as a tag in onBindViewHolder. 
Something like this:
"holder.timer.setTag(position);"
And than in  playMyMedia add this check before updating:
if(position != holder.timer.getTag()){
return;
}

Comment: actually the updation call occurs in the fragment, I have made a custom listener for that. And setTag() also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where you call `updateTimer`, but I assume that you call it from within `callback.onPlayClickListener(..)` and `callback.onPauseClickListener(..)`.

**First**, do not pass it the `position` you've got as a parameter in click listeners, but as [documentation states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) you should use [ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()) method. Note, that when you use the value of the position you should also check that it is different from `RecuclerView.NO_POSITION` each time and only then use it. Make your position parameter not final in all methods. It will prevent you from making mistakes. Each time you want to use position in click listeners use `myChatViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`

**Second**, since you cache `position` value in the Runnable anyway, this is probably not enough. So you should pass `myChatViewHolder.timer` as a parameter to `updateTimer` and get rid of first two lines. In the end you call `updateTimer` like this:

```
updateTimer(myChatViewHolder.timer);
```

and your 'updateTimer' now is:

```
public void updateTimer(final TextView timer) {

    r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int currentDuration;
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                currentDuration = player.getCurrentPosition();
                timer.setText("" + milliSecondsToTimer((long) currentDuration));
                timer.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            } else {
                timer.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        }
    };

    timer.post(r);
}
```

More from the documentation on this matter:

> RecyclerView will not call onBindViewHolder() method again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only use the position parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this method and should not keep a copy of it.

Comment: ok , I did as you said and passed the TextView as an argument to updateTimer() method , still I am having the same problem, random TextView at random positons are also updated

Comment: Probably I'll have to see all your code. It could be not only RecyclerView issue